# WCF Web.config Error : “This collection already contains an address with scheme http”

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7, web-config

Firstly, I tried adding the below code in web.config

```
 <system.serviceModel> 
         <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" /> 
    </system.serviceModel>
```

But no luck I was still getting the same error.

Then, I tried adding below code also in web.config

```
 <system.serviceModel> 
         <serviceHostingEnvironment> 
              <baseAddressPrefixFilters> 
                   <add prefix="http://www.YourHostedDomainName.com"/> 
              </baseAddressPrefixFilters> 
         </serviceHostingEnvironment> 
    </system.serviceModel>
```

But still no luck. Now I am getting this error:

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.

Erron on Source File: D:\Site\Website\service\web.config Line:52

Complete web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="DESKNET.Public.TEServices.TEAPI" behaviorConfiguration="DESKNET.Public.TEServices.TEAPIBehaviour" >
        <endpoint address="SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBindingSOAP" contract="DESKNET.Public.TEServices.ITEAPI" ></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="REST" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBindingREST" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehaviour" contract="DESKNET.Public.TEServices.ITEAPI" ></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DESKNET.Public.TEServices.TEAPIBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="DESKNET.Public.TEServices.UserAuthentication, DESKNET"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBindingSOAP">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBindingSOAP"></binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBindingREST">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        <!-- </binding> -->
        <!-- </binding> -->
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
     <baseAddressPrefixFilters> 
         <add prefix="http://YourHostedDomainName.com"/> 
     </baseAddressPrefixFilters> 
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share the full web.config file to help you better?

Comment: I have added full web.config ,please have look

Answer (score 0):

About the error, please refer to my previous reply, It has nothing with WCF configuration.
Besides, there is something wrong with your current WCF configuration. I have revised it, please refer to below.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
      <!--replace the name attribute with your service implemented class-->
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1" >
        <!--replace the contract attribute with your service contract-->
        <endpoint address="SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1" ></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="REST" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehaviour" contract="WcfService3.IService1" ></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

It supports both `Rest` style and `SOAP` style web service. Besides, you need to configure a certificate to enable custom Username authentication. I have removed it within the above codes.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.